# Pandas calculating difference between rows

Tags: python, pandas, row, date-difference

My goal is to calculate the day difference from Start/End comparing to End.  I know I have to group them by Id but I'm not sure how to perform the difference between the Day.

I tried df['length'] = -(df.groupby('Id')['Day'].diff()).  This doesn't compare to End, it only computes the difference whenever the Status changes.

df

```
Id Day Status

111 1 Start

111 5 End

222 2 Begin

222 7 End

333 1 Start

333 3 Begin

333 7 End
```

Ideal result would be:

```
Id Day Status Length

111 1 Start 4

111 5 End 

222 2 Begin 5

222 7 End

333 1 Start 6 (since we Start on Day 1 and End on day 7)

333 3 Begin 4 (since we Begin on Day 3 and End on day 7)

333 7 End
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `apply` with `.iloc`

```
df.groupby('Id').Day.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[-1]-x).replace(0,np.nan)
Out[187]: 
0    4.0
1    NaN
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    6.0
5    4.0
6    NaN
Name: Day, dtype: float64
```

After assign it back

```
df['Length']=df.groupby('Id').Day.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[-1]-x).replace(0,np.nan)
df
Out[189]: 
    Id  Day Status  Length
0  111    1  Start     4.0
1  111    5    End     NaN
2  222    2  Begin     5.0
3  222    7    End     NaN
4  333    1  Start     6.0
5  333    3  Begin     4.0
6  333    7    End     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I need to look into how to use apply and iloc more.

Comment: @TylerNG aha yw

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method with `groupby` + `transform` -

```
v = df.groupby('Id').Day.transform('last') - df.Day
df['Length'] = v.mask(v == 0)  # or v.mask(df.Status.eq('End'))

df

    Id  Day Status  Length
0  111    1  Start     4.0
1  111    5    End     NaN
2  222    2  Begin     5.0
3  222    7    End     NaN
4  333    1  Start     6.0
5  333    3  Begin     4.0
6  333    7    End     NaN
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000000, ignore_index=True)

# apply + iloc
%timeit df.groupby('Id').Day.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[-1]-x).replace(0,np.nan)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.49 s per loop

# transform + mask 
%%timeit
v = df.groupby('Id').Day.transform('last') - df.Day
df['Length'] = v.mask(v == 0)

1 loop, best of 3: 294 ms per loop
```

Comment: very nice approach

Comment: @TylerNG If performance was important, I'd go with this. But it's upto you. I like Wen a lot, no complaints with his answer.

Comment: O my ..5 times ! Great answer !:-)

Comment: @Wen Cheers, I was a bit surprised at the performance difference myself. Yours is good too, on smaller data of course ;-)

Comment: There is o doubt , `apply` is slow : -)

Comment: Oppps...*There is no doubt *